# TableView is not visible until click

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am using JavaFX and I have a strange problem. The follwing code is in the constructor of a class, which inherits Stage. The code is work in progress.

```
    // this works fine, the chart is displayed
    Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 1000, 600);
    // table is not shown until I click on the window
    Scene scene = new Scene(bidTable, 1000, 600);

    this.setTitle("Auction chart");
    this.setScene(scene);
```

What do I wrong? No errors and table with content is shown after I click on the window. Before it's just a white window.

EDIT:
I removed the chart just the table:

```
public class AuctionChart extends Stage {

    private final TableView<Bid> bidTable = new TableView<Bid>();

    private final TableColumn<Bid, String> bidColumn = new TableColumn<Bid, String>("Bid");

    private final TableColumn<Bid, String> utilityColumn = new TableColumn<Bid, String>("Utility");

    private final TableColumn<Bid, String> profitColumn = new TableColumn<Bid, String>("Profit");

    private final NumberFormat fm = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    public AuctionChart() {

        initialize();

        bidTable.getColumns().addAll(bidColumn, utilityColumn, profitColumn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bidTable, 1000, 600);

        this.setTitle("Auction chart");
        this.setScene(scene);
    }

    public void setTowns(List<Town> towns) {

        bidTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(towns.get(0).getGebote()));
    }

    private void initialize() {
        bidColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(fm.format(cellData.getValue().getBid())));
        utilityColumn
                .setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(fm.format(cellData.getValue().getUtility())));
        profitColumn
                .setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(fm.format(cellData.getValue().getProfit())));
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
    AuctionChart stage = new AuctionChart();
    stage.setTowns(towns);
    stage.show();
```

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here to be able to figure out what you might be doing wrong. Please create and post a [MCVE].

Comment: If you could actually make that example complete and verifiable, someone might be able to help...

Comment: It's not simple. I am pretty sure, the problem is that I start the new stage, which contains the table, with a button from another stage.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. The problem is there's nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted, so the issue is likely caused by code you haven't posted. If someone writes the missing code in to test it out (even if there is someone prepared to devote that much time to helping you for free), the chances they will recreate the same issue are pretty slim. So you need to *create* an MCVE (not post your entire application) which shows the same problem.

Comment: Unrelated: don't _extend_ Stage ... instead _use_ it.- that's what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, it isn't a JavaFx Problem. It's an issue with concurrent threads in the application's backend.